# Hibernation doesn’t work when it is booted from external SSD drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I have an external SSD drive connected to my laptop through a USB C port. I can start Windows flawlessly from the SSD. Windows was installed when the laptop was directly connected to the motherboard on another dead laptop.

When I click on the hibernate option, it seems that the process of hibernation finishes without any errors or issues. But when I turn on the laptop, it starts a fresh session as if it was turned off instead of hibernating.

Wondering what can be the source of the issue and how to fix it. So I can use my USB connected SSD like an internal one.

Comment: This is likely occurring because your Windows install is starting from SSD. Can it not start normally?  Hibernation writes a system image and so must start normally.

Comment: @John it starts normally from SSD it only does not restore hibernation from SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate mode saves your the information to your disk. So if you are starting from your SSD (you said "I can start Windows flawlessly from my SSD.") hibernate will get data from both external SSD and main disk.

See  [Hibernate](https://paylesspower.com/blog/computer-sleep-vs-hibernate/)

> Two computer modes that require distinguishing are sleep mode and
> hibernate, which are often used synonymously but are not in fact the
> same thing. Sleep mode is an energy-saving state that allows activity
> to resume when fully powered. Hibernate mode is also meant to be
> power-saving but differs from sleep mode in what is done with your
> data. Sleep mode stores the documents and files you are operating into
> the RAM, using a small amount of power in the process. Hibernate mode
> essentially does the same thing, but saves the information to your
> hard disk, which allows your computer to be turned off completely and
> use no energy. When you turn your it back on, your hard drive allows
> your work to be brought right back to where you left off. Hibernate is
> mainly meant for laptops and is best used in the event you are not
> planning to use your computer for a long period but want to keep your
> work up.

If you removed the SSD (nothing prevents that) then Hibernate could not come back to life.

So what you are trying to do will not work.

Set your computer to start normally (without external SSD) and set up power management and then Hibernate will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your time writing this. I'm not sure if you get the question correctly. My Windows is installed on the external SSD. The SSD is connected when I hibernate or start the machine. The internal disk is not writable and I guess Windows does not care about it. The issue is when I hibernate the machine it shows no error or issue. But when I start it, it boots a fresh session instead of the hibernated session.

Comment: I have also done the same. Got Windows om external disk. This is Windows problem - computer will die and can't be resumed if Windows is started from USB drive. If the same Windows is started from SATA port, then there is no problem. Also, computer will not shut down/restart if Windows started from USB drive has got option "Automatically restart" for system failure disabled. Minidump.dmp does not get created though. This is big Windows problem, I think only Microsoft can solve it, but Windows on USB drive is not their interest.